# Jest: Compare DOM element with JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, html, object, jestjs

I have an HTML template with many inputs, like this:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" value={person.firstName} disabled={isInViewMode}>
  <label for="lname">Last name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" value={person.lastName} disabled={isInViewMode}>
  ...
</form>
```

I can check what's in the DOM like so...

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
expect(inputs[0].type).toBe("text");
expect(inputs[0].value).toBe("John");
expect(inputs[0].disabled).toBe(false);
```

Which works, but pretty often, instead of repeating `expect(...).toBe(...)`, I prefer to use a JavaScript object to define my expectations, like this:

```js
const expectedInputs = [
  { type: "text", value: "John", disabled: false },
  ...
];
```

I can make assertions about `expectedInputs` like this:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
expectedInputs.forEach((expectedInput, idx) => {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(expectedInput).forEach(key => {
    expect(inputs[idx][key].toBe(expectedInput[key]);
  }
});
```

This is useful for avoiding verbose test code, in scenarios using [`test.each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout), etc.  But the pitfall is that when something fails, I often can't readily see which expected DOM element it failed on (because I no longer have an object-specific line number to refer to):

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: undefined

  192 |         expectedInputs.forEach((input, idx) => {
  193 |             Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input).forEach(key => {
> 194 |                 expect(inputs[idx][key]).toBe(input[key]);
      |                 ^
  195 |             });
  196 |         });
```

This would be resolved if I could compare an entire JS object to a DOM element object.  But I'm having trouble figuring out how to represent the `HTMLElement` so it can be compared to a vanilla JS object.  For example, I've tried using `Object.assign()` to create a JS object with the `HTMLElement`'s properties.  But I'm not getting the right properties on the resulting object:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: ObjectContaining {"disabled": true, "tagName": "INPUT", "type": "text", "value": "John"}
Received: {"$fromTemplate$": true, "$shadowResolver$": undefined, Symbol(SameObject caches): {"classList": {"0": "slds-p-vertical_none"}}}

  192 |         expectedInputs.forEach((expectedInput, idx) => {
  193 |             const inputObj = Object.assign({}, inputs[idx]);
> 194 |             expect(inputObj).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(expectedInput));
      |             ^
  195 |         });
```

Is there some way to either A) convert an `HTMLElement` to something that can be compared using `expect(...).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(...))`, or B) some other not-too-complex way to achieve a more informative failure message using Jest in this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking. You want to turn the `HTMLElement` for this

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" value={person.firstName} disabled={isInViewMode}>
```

into this

```js
{type: "text", id: "fname", value: //...
```

You can use the [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) which is a collection of the element's attributes. Its not an array--its a [`NamedNodeMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) so you can `Array.from` it--and then either `map` or `reduce` into the object representation you want.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("foo");
const obj1 = {};
Array.from(input.attributes)
    .map(attribute => {
    obj1[attribute.name]=attribute.value;
});

console.log(obj1); // {id: "foo", name: "bar", value: "baz"}

// or

const obj2 = Array.from(input.attributes)
    .reduce((acc, attr) => {
        acc[attr.name] = attr.value;
        return acc;
    }, {});
    
console.log(obj2);  // {id: "foo", name: "bar", value: "baz"}
```

```html
<input id="foo" name="bar" value="baz">
```

Comment: I tested in JSBin, and this concept actually works in a vanilla JS environment.  See https://jsbin.com/xedatog/3/edit?html,js,output ... So, upvoted!  My problem is, in my actual real-life scenario (testing Salesforce Lightning Web Components with Jest), most properties that can be accessed via dot notation in the HTMLElement (e.g. `value`, `disabled`) don't show up via `input.attributes` for some reason.  I'm uncertain how this could be the case.

Comment: For the record, I'm now pretty sure my Salesforce-specific issue is related to what was discussed in this thread: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264202

Comment: While I think you've effectively answered the question, I've opened up a new thread to clarify my REAL question, which I now understand to be about IDL attributes, not content attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693648

Comment: Ah interesting with the IDL ones. Well for the object that has your `expectedInputs`, and a given element `input` what about just making an object that has the keys in `expectedInputs` mapped to the values on the `input` element, something like this 

`obj3 = Object.keys(expectedInputs).reduce((acc,attr)=>{acc[attr.name]=input[attr.name];return acc;},{});`

Comment: That's another solution I didn't think of.  Nice!