# Get all IDL attributes for an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, attributes, jsdom, idl

I know it's possible to get all ***content attributes*** on a a standard `HTMLElement` like this:

```html
<input type="text" value="John" />
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const attrs = Array.from(input.attributes);
console.log(attrs.map(a => a.name + ': ' a.value)); // [ "type: text", "value: John" ]
```

I'm working in a world (Salesforce Lightning Web Components) where ***[IDL attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#content_versus_idl_attributes)*** (i.e. those you can access via dot notation) aren't always exposed as content attributes at runtime.  For example, for the following template:

```html
<lightning-input label="First Name" value="John" data-id="fname">
</lightning-input>
```

I get the following behavior:

```js
const input = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-input");
// I can get all these IDL attributes via dot notation
console.log(input.label); // First Name
console.log(input.value); // John
console.log(input.dataset.id); // fname

const attrs = Array.from(input.attributes);
// But they don't all show up here
console.log(attrs.map(a => a.name + ': ' a.value)); // [ "data-id: fname" ]
```

As you can see, I can access properties like `label` and `value` via dot notation, but not via [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

What I'm looking for is a way to introspect all IDL attributes on an element, for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They exist on the prototype, so you can examine the prototype's JS properties:

```js
const getKeys = obj => obj
  ? Object.keys(obj).concat(getKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)))
  : [];
console.log(
  getKeys(document.querySelector('input'))
);
```

```html
<input>
```